# Acceder a la clase hija desde el padre | Java

Tags: java, array, herencia

Tengo una clase abstracta `Publicaciones` y dos clases hijas: `Libro` y `Revista`.

Tengo un `ArrayList` de Publicaciones, donde guardo objetos `Libro` y objetos `Revista`, pero a la hora de acceder a los atributos de `libro` y `revista` (los que no heredan de la clase padre) mediante publicaciones `.get(i)` reconoce a los objetos como de tipo *Publicaciones* y no como lo que son, de clase `Libro` y `Revista`, respectivamente.

Sé que el tipo de objetos que almacena el `ArrayList` son `Publicaciones`, pero no quiero hacer un `ArrayList` para cada tipo de publicación.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer esto? O quizás esté planteando mal el ejercicio.

```
public void listarLibrosAutor() throws IOException{
    BufferedReader teclado = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String autor;

    System.out.println("Introduce el autor: ");
    autor = teclado.readLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < publicaciones.size(); i++) {

        if(publicaciones.get(i) instanceof Libro && publicaciones.get(i).getNombreAutor()){


        }
    }
}
```

El método es para listar los libros a partir de un autor, en el momento en el que intento acceder al atributo `nombreAutor` es cuando me salta el error.

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Por favor, edita tu pregunta incluyendo el código relevante para poder reproducir tu problema. Por favor, sigue esta guía: [mcve].

Comment: Sí, como dice @toledano sería mucho más fácil ver tu error si indicas el código que tienes actualmente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para acceder a los parametros de cada clase hija tendrías que hacer un cast a la clase concreta. Ejemplo:

```
Publicaciones p = list.get(i);
if (p instanceof Libro){
    Libro l = (Libro) p;
    l.getXXX();
}
else if (p instanceof Revista){
    Revista r = (Revista) p;
    r.getYYY();
}
```

Aviso: esta no es una manera "elegante" de resolver el problema (digamos que no es orientado a objetos 100%).

Comment: Tu solución es la mejor para su diseño que efectivamente deja que desear para lo que está diciendo.

Comment: Correcto. Y aunque seguramente hay una manera más "elegante" o más orientado objeto de hacerlo, no hay manera de sugerir una mejor opción a menos que OP comparta su código para poder ver de qué forma necesita leer los atributos.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Esta solución me ha servido. Ya solo me queda intentar conseguir una solución que case mejor con el paradigma de objetos,

Comment: @Daniel Plata, existe un patrón de diseño llamado Visitor que puedes utilizar en este caso.  Utiliza una técnica conocida como "double-dispatch", ya que "despacha" una llamada dependiendo del tipo.  Puedes encontrar varias referencias.  Esta es solo una: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/java/2

Lo que tienes que evaluar es si el remedio es mejor que la solución presentada arriba.  Incorporar un patrón de diseño vale la pena si vas a tener una jerarquía de clases, y necesita planearse desde el principio de un diseño. Si sólo tienes un par de clases, lo de arriba funciona.